# Item command not firing in lazy load control

Tags: c#, asp.net, lazy-loading, repeater, itemcommand

I have a repeater, which is dynamically created on tab index change of AJAX tabcontainer. But, when I try to delete the item from the repeater, it doesn't fire the item command of the repeater.

Dynamically binding of repeater

```
public void bindControl()
{
           dset = GetWorklistItems();
            if (dset.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                rpt_worklistitems.DataSource = dset;
                rpt_worklistitems.DataBind();
            }
 }
```

Comment: Please provide some code at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using the following code:

```
If (Page.IsPostBack)
  return;
if (dset.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            rpt_worklistitems.DataSource = dset;
            rpt_worklistitems.DataBind();
        }
```